# What are the complexities of memory-unmanaged programming?

Tags: low-level, garbage-collection

Or in other words, what specific problems did automated garbage collection solve? I've never done low-level programming, so I don't know how complicated can freeing resources get.

The kind of bugs that GC addresses seem (at least to an external observer) the kind of things that a programmer that knows well his language, libraries, concepts, idioms, etc, wouldn't do. But I could be wrong: is manual memory handling intrinsically complicated?

Comment: Please expand to tell us how your question is not answered by the Wikipedia article on [garbace collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) and more specifically the section on [its benefits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)#Benefits)

Comment: Another benefit is security, e.g. buffer overruns are highly exploitable and many other security vulnerabilities arise from memory (mis)management.

Comment: @StuperUser: That has nothing to do with the origin of the memory. You can buffer overrun memory that came from a GC just fine. The fact that GC languages usually prevent this is orthogonal, and languages that are less than thirty years behind the GC technology you're comparing them to also offer buffer overrun protection.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> I've never done low-level programming, so I don't know how complicated
> can freeing resources get.

Funny how the definition of "low-level" changes over time.  When I was first learning to program, any language that provided a standardized heap model that makes a simple allocate/free pattern possible was considered high-level indeed.  In *low-level programming*, you'd have to keep track of the memory yourself, (not the allocations, but the memory locations themselves!), or write your own heap allocator if you were feeling really fancy.

Having said that, there's really nothing scary or "complicated" about it, at all.  Remember when you were a child and your mom told you to put away your toys when you're done playing with them, that she is not your maid and wasn't going to clean up your room for you?  Memory management is simply this same principle applied to code.  (GC is like having a maid who *will* clean up after you, but she's very lazy and slightly clueless.)  The principle of it is simple: Each variable in your code has one and only one owner, and it’s the responsibility of that owner to free the variable’s memory when it is no longer needed.  ([The Single Ownership Principle](http://tech.turbu-rpg.com/106/delphi-memory-management-made-simple))  This requires one call per allocation, and several schemes exist that automate ownership and cleanup in one way or another so you don't even have to write that call into your own code.

Garbage collection is supposed to solve two problems.  It invariably does a very bad job at one of them, and depending on the implementation may or may not do well with the other one.  The problems are memory leaks (holding on to memory after you're done with it) and dangling references (freeing memory before you're done with it.)  Let's look at both issues:

Dangling references: Discussing this one first because it's the really serious one.  You've got two pointers to the same object.  You free one of them and don't notice the other one.  Then at some later point you attempt to read (or write to or free) the second one.  Undefined behavior ensues.  If you don't notice it, you can easily corrupt your memory.  Garbage collection is supposed to make this problem impossible by ensuring that nothing is ever freed until all references to it are gone.  In a fully-managed language, this almost works, until you have to deal with external, unmanaged memory resources.  Then it's right back to square 1.  And in a non-managed language, things are trickier still.  (Poke around on Mozilla's bug-tracker for Firefox sometime and see if you can find how many different crash bugs were caused by their garbage collector screwing up and freeing things too early!)

Fortunately, dealing with this issue is basically a solved problem.  You don't need a garbage collector, you need a *debugging memory manager.*  I use Delphi, for example, and with a single external library and a simple compiler directive I can set the allocator to "Full Debug Mode."  This adds a negligible (less than 5%) performance overhead in return for enabling some features that keep track of used memory.  If I free an object, it fills its memory with `0x80` bytes (easily recognizable in the debugger) and if I ever attempt to call a virtual method (including the destructor) on a freed object, it notices and interrupts the program with an error box with three stack traces--when the object was created, when it was freed, and where I am now--plus some other useful information, then raises an exception. This is obviously not suitable for release builds, but it makes tracking down and fixing dangling reference issues trivial.

The second issue is memory leaks.  This is what happens when you continue to hold on to allocated memory when you no longer need it.  It can happen in any language, with or without garbage collection, and can only be fixed by writing your code right.  Garbage collection helps to mitigate *one specific form* of memory leak, the kind that happens when you have no valid references to a piece of memory that has not yet been freed, which means the memory stays allocated until the program ends.  Unfortunately, the only way to accomplish this in an automated manner is by turning every allocation into a memory leak!

I'm probably going to get dinged by GC proponents if I try to say something like that, so allow me to explain.  Remember that the definition of a memory leak is holding on to allocated memory when you no longer need it.  In addition to having no references to something, you can also leak memory by having an unnecessary reference to it, such as holding it in a container object when you should have freed it.  I've seen some memory leaks caused by doing this, and they are very difficult to track down whether you have a GC or not, since they involve a perfectly valid reference to the memory and there are no clear "bugs" for debugging tools to catch.  As far as I know, there is no automated tool that allows you to catch this type of memory leak.

So a garbage collector only concerns itself with the no-references variety of memory leaks, because that's the only type that can be dealt with in an automated fashion.  If it could watch all your references to everything and free every object as soon as it has zero references pointing to it, it would be perfect, at least with regards to the no-references problem.  Doing this in an automated manner is called *reference counting,* and it can be done in some limited situations, but it has its own issues to deal with.  (For example, object A holding a reference to object B, which holds a reference to object A. In a reference-counting scheme, neither object can be freed automatically, even when there are no external references to either A or B.)  So garbage collectors use *tracing* instead: Start with a set of known-good objects, find all objects that they reference, find all objects that *they* reference, and so on recursively until you've found everything.  Whatever does not get found in the tracing process is garbage and can be thrown away.  (Doing this successfully, of course, requires a managed language that puts certain restrictions on the type system to ensure that the tracing garbage collector can always tell the difference between a reference and some random piece of memory that happens to look like a pointer.)

There are two problems with tracing.  First, it's slow, and while it's happening the program has to be more or less paused to avoid race conditions.  This can lead to noticeable execution hiccups when the program is supposed to be interacting with a user, or bogged-down performance in a server app.  This can be mitigated by various techniques, such as breaking allocated memory up into "generations" on the principle that if an allocation doesn't get collected the first time you try, it's likely to stick around for a while.  Both the .NET framework and the JVM use generational garbage collectors.

Unfortunately, this feeds into the second problem: memory not getting freed when you're done with it.  Unless the tracing runs immediately after you finish with an object, it will stick around until the next trace, or even longer if it makes it past the first generation.  In fact, [one of the best explanations of the .NET garbage collector I've seen](http://blog.barrkel.com/2009/12/commonly-confused-tidbits-re-net.html) explains that, in order to make the process as fast as possible, the GC has to defer collection for as long as it can!  So the problem of memory leaks is "solved" rather bizarrely by *leaking as much memory as possible for as long as possible!*  This is what I mean when I say that a GC turns every allocation into a memory leak.  In fact, [there is no guarantee that any given object will *ever* be collected.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5737813/32914)

Why is this an issue, when the memory still gets reclaimed when needed?  For a couple of reasons.  First, imagine allocating a large object (a bitmap, for example,) that takes a significant amount of memory.  And then soon after you're done with it, you need another large object that takes the same (or close to the same) amount of memory.  Had the first object been freed, the second one can reuse its memory.  But on a garbage-collected system, you may well be still waiting for the next trace to run, and so you end up unnecessarily wasting memory for a second large object.  It's basically a race condition.

Second, holding memory unnecessarily, especially in large amounts, can cause problems in a modern multitasking system.  If you take up too much physical memory, it can cause your program or other programs to have to page (swap some of their memory out to disc) which really slows things down.  For certain systems, such as servers, paging can not only slow the system down, [it can crash the whole thing if it's under load.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040317-00/?p=40223)

Like the dangling references problem, the no-references problem can be solved with a debugging memory manager.  Again, I'll mention the Full Debug Mode from Delphi's FastMM memory manager, since it's the one I'm most familiar with.  (I'm sure similar systems exist for other languages.)

When a program running under FastMM terminates, you can optionally have it report the existence of all allocations that never got freed.  Full Debug Mode takes it a step further: it can save a file to disc containing not only the type of allocation, but a stack trace from when it was allocated and other debug info, for each leaked allocation.  This makes tracking down no-references memory leaks trivial.

When you really look at it, garbage collection may or may not do well with preventing dangling references, and universally does a bad job at handling memory leaks.  Its one virtue, in fact, is not the garbage collection itself, but a side-effect: it provides an automated way to perform heap compaction.  This can prevent an arcane problem (memory exhaustion through heap fragmentation) that can kill programs that run continually for a long time and have a high degree of memory churn, and heap compaction is pretty much impossible without garbage collection.  However, any good memory allocator these days uses buckets to minimize fragmentation, which means that fragmentation only truly becomes a problem in extreme circumstances.  For a program in which heap fragmentation is likely to be a problem, it's advisable to use a compacting garbage collector.  But IMO in any other case, the use of garbage collection is premature optimization, and better solutions exist to the problems that it "solves."

Comment: The single ownership principle doesn't necessarily work in practice.  Given a data object used in several places, it isn't trivial to assign a single owner or figure out when to release the memory.  Even relatively primitive GC (like reference counting) can solve that problem.

Comment: @David: Reference counting is an example of the single-ownership principle, and it's the appropriate way to deal with the situation you describe, as the linked article explains.

Comment: I love this answer - I keep reading it every now and then. Can't come up with a relevant remark so all I can say is - thank you.

Comment: I'd like to point out that yes, GCs tend to "leak" memory (at least for a while), but this isn't an issue because it will collect the memory when the memory allocator cannot allocate memory prior to collection. With a non-GC language, a leak always stays a leak, meaning you actually can run out of memory due to too much uncollected memory. "garbage collection is premature optimization"... GC isn't an optimization and was not designed with that in mind. Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: @ThomasEding: GC certainly is an optimization; it optimizes for *minimal programmer effort,* at the expense of performance and various other program quality metrics.

Comment: Funny that you point to Mozilla's bug tracker at one point, because Mozilla has come to a quite different conclusion. Firefox had and continues to have countless security issues coming from memory management mistakes. Note that this is not about how easy it was to fix the error once detected --- usually the damage is already done by the time the developers become aware of the issue. Mozilla is funding the Rust programming language precisely to help prevent such errors from being introduced in the first place.

Comment: Rust does not use garbage-collection though, it uses reference-counting exactly how Mason is describing, just with extensive compile-time checks rather than having to use a debugger to detect errors at run-time...

Comment: @MasonWheeler - You are an artist!

Comment: Back in the day I wrote a Java class “MemoryLeak”. new MemoryLeak (Object x) (can’t remember the syntax anymore) would stash x in a place where the GC saw it as reachable, but no Java code could access it.

Comment: MasonWheeler: Reference counting is really multiple ownership.

Answer (score 13):

Considering a non-garbage-collected memory management technique from an equivalent era as the garbage collectors in use in current popular systems, such as C++'s RAII. Given this approach, then the cost of not using automated garbage collection is minimal, and GC introduces plenty of it's own problems. As such, I'd suggest that "Not much" is the answer to your problem.

Remember, when people think of non-GC, they think `malloc` and `free`. But this is a giant logical fallacy- you'd be comparing non-GC resource management of the early 1970s to the garbage collectors of the late 90s. This is obviously a rather unfair comparison- the garbage collectors that were in use when `malloc` and `free` were designed were much too slow to run any meaningful program, if I remember correctly. Comparing something from a vaguely equivalent time period, e.g. `unique_ptr`, is much more meaningful.

Garbage collectors can handle reference cycles more easily, although these are pretty rare experiences. In addition, GCs can just "throw up" code because the GC will take care of all memory management, meaning that they can lead to faster dev cycles.

On the other hand, they tend to run into massive problems when dealing with memory that came from anywhere except their own GC pool. In addition, they lose a lot of their benefit when concurrency is involved, because you have to consider object ownership anyway.

Edit: Many of the things you mention have nothing to do with GC. You're confusing memory management and object orientation. See, here's the thing: If you program in a completey unmanaged system, like C++, you can have as much bounds checking as you like, and the Standard container classes do offer it. There's nothing GC about bounds checking, for example, or strong typing.

The problems you mention are solved by object-orientation, not GC. The origin of array memory and making sure you don't write outside it are orthogonal concepts.

Edit: It is worth noting that more advanced techniques can avoid the need for any form of dynamic memory allocation at all. For example, consider the use of [this](http://ideone.com/clone/R3W3k), which implements Y-combination in C++ with no dynamic allocation at all.

Comment: The extended discussion here has been cleaned up: if everyone can take it to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21) to discuss the topic further, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @DeadMG, do you know what combinator is supposed to do? It is supposed to COMBINE. By definition, combinator is a function without any free variables.

Comment: @SK-logic: I could have chosen to implement it purely by template and not have any member variables. But then you would not be able to pass in closures, which significantly limits it's usefulness. Care to come to chat?

Comment: @DeadMG, a definition is crystal clear. No free variables. I consider any language "functional enough" if it is possible to define Y-combinator (properly, not your way). A big "+" is if it is possible to define it via S, K and I combinators. Otherwise language is not expressive enough.

Comment: @SK-logic: Why don't you *come to the chat*, like the kind moderator asked? Also, a Y-combinator is a Y-combinator, it does the job or it doesn't. The Haskell version of the Y-combinator is basically exactly the same as this one, it's just that the state expressed is hidden from you.

Comment: @DeadMG Your link to an example is dead.

Answer (score 11):

The "freedom from having to worry about freeing resources" that garbage-collected languages supposedly provide is to a *considerable* extent an illusion. Keep adding stuff into a map without ever removing any, and you will soon understand what I am talking about.

In fact, memory leaks are quite frequent in programs written in GCed languages, because these languages tend to make the programmers lazy, and make them acquire a false sense of security that the language will always somehow (magically) take care of every object that they do not wish to have to think about anymore.

Garbage collection is simply a necessary facility for languages that have another, more noble goal: to treat everything as a pointer to an object, and at the same time hide from the programmer the fact that it is a pointer, so that the programmer cannot commit suicide by attempting pointer arithmetic and the like. Everything being an object means that GCed languages need to allocate objects far more often than non-GCed languages, which means that if they put the burden of deallocating those objects on the programmer, they would be immensely unattractive.

Also, garbage collection is useful in order to provide the programmer with the ability to write tight code, manipulating objects inside expressions, in a functional programming fashion, without having to break the expressions down into separate statements in order to provide for the deallocation of every single object that participates in the expression.

Aside from all that, please note that in the beginning of my answer I wrote "it is to a *considerable* extent an illusion". I did not write that *it is* an illusion. I did not even write that *it is mostly* an illusion. Garbage collection is useful in taking away from the programmer the menial task of attending to the deallocation of his objects. So, in this sense it is a productivity feature.

Answer (score 4):

Garbage collector does not address any "bugs". It is a neccessary part of some high level languages semantics. With a GC it is possible to define higher levels of abstractions, such as lexical closures and alike, whereas with a manual memory management those abstractions will be leaky, unnecessarily bound to the lower levels of the resource management.

A "single ownership principle", mentioned in the comments, is quite a good example of such a leaky abstraction. A developer should not be concerned at all about the number of links to any particular elementary data structure instance, otherwise any piece of code would not be generic and transparent without a huge number of additional (not directly visible in the code itself) limitations and requirements. Such a code cannot be composed into a higher level code, which is an intolerable breach of the layers of responsibility separation principle (a major building block of the software engineering, unfortunately not respected at all by most of the low level developers).

Comment: +1. That's what I am also talking about. I just do it with more words and less accurate terms.

Comment: Funny.  Delphi managed to implement lexical closures a couple years back with no GC...

Comment: @Mason Wheeler, even C++ implements a very limited form of closures. But is not nearly a proper, generally usable closure.

Comment: @SK-logic: Well, I haven't used C++'s very limited closures.  I've use Delphi's though, and I assure you, they're real, generally usable lexical closures, made possible without a garbage collector and without memory leaks because unlike C++, Delphi is a very well-designed language.

Comment: You're wrong. No GC can protect you from the fact that you cannot refer to stack variables. And it's funny- in C++, you can take the "Copy a pointer to a dynamically allocated variable which will be appropriately and automatically destroyed" approach, too.

Comment: @DeadMG, again, stop thinking so low-level. I knew that C++ is a brain-damaging thing...

Comment: @MasonWheeler, no, there are no real closures in Delphi, sorry to disappoint you.

Comment: @DeadMG, don't you see that your code is leaking low level entities through any other level you build on top?

Comment: @SK-Logic: OK, we have a terminology problem.  What's your definition of "real closure," and what can they do that Delphi's closures can't?  (And including anything about memory management in your definition is moving the goal posts. Let's talk about behavior, not implementation details.)

Comment: @Mason Wheeler, to be precise, I define closure exactly as it is defined for a simple untyped lambda calculus.

Comment: @SK-Logic: ...and do you have an example of something that can be done with simple-untyped-lambda-closures that Delphi's closures cannot accomplish?

Comment: @Mason Wheeler, try implementing Churh-encoded lists and Church numerals, for a starter.

Comment: @SK-logic: So a recursive "add 1 to this" function and a simple linked list?  They both look trivial to me.  What is there in either one that you can't do with Delphi's closures?  (And why in the world would anyone want to use Church numerals in real code in the first place?  Do you have any *practical* examples?)

Comment: @mason Wheeler, not a "simple linked list", but a Church-encoded list. Feel the difference. An ability to represent something as trivial as Church numbers is just an indication of an ability to do more high level high-order programming.

Answer (score 2):

Really, managing your own memory is just one more potential source of bugs.

If you forget a call to `free` (or whatever the equivalent is in whichever language you're using), your program can pass all of its tests, but leak memory.  And in a moderately complex program, it's quite easy to overlook a call to `free`.

Comment: Missed `free` is not the worst thing. Early `free` is much more devastating.

Comment: And the double `free`!

Comment: Hehe!  I'd go along with both of the two comments above.  I've never committed one of these transgressions myself (as far as I know), but I can see how terrible the effects might be.  The answer from quant_dev says it all - mistakes with memory allocation and de-allocation are notoriously hard to find and fix.

Comment: This is a fallacy. You're comparing "early 1970" to "late 1990". The GCs that existed at the time at which `malloc` and `free` was the non-GC way to go were vastly too slow to be useful for anything. You need to be comparing it to a modern non-GC approach, like RAII.

Comment: @DeadMG RAII is not manual memory management

Comment: @quant_dev: Don't need to have this discussion in two separate comment threads :P

Comment: @quant_dev: unique_ptr/shared_ptr that's all you need nowadays.

Comment: In a moderately complex program, it's also trivial to *find* your overlooked Free call with the use of a debugging memory manager.

Answer (score 2):

Manual resource is not only tedious, but also difficult to debug. In other words, not only is it tedious to get it right, but also when you get it wrong, it's not obvious where the problem is. This is because, unlike for example division by zero, the effects of the error show up away from the source of error, and connecting the dots requires time, attention and experience.

Answer (score 1):

I think garbage collection gets a lot of credit for language improvements that have nothing to do with GC, other than being part of one big wave of progress.

The one solid benefit to GC I know of is that you can set an object free in your program and know it will go away when everyone is done with it.  You can pass it to another class's method and not worry about it.  You don't care what other methods it gets passed to, or what other classes reference it.  (Memory leaks are the responsibility of the class referencing an object, not the class that created it.)

Without GC you have to track the entire life cycle of the allocated memory.  Every time you pass an address up or down from the subroutine that created it, you have an out-of-control reference to that memory.  In the bad old days, even with only one thread, recursion and an ornery operating system (Windows NT) made it impossible for me to control access to allocated memory.  I had to rig the *free* method in my own allocation system to keep memory blocks around for a time until all the references got cleared out.  The holding time was pure guesswork, but it worked.

So that's the only GC benefit I know of, but I couldn't live without it.  I don't think any kind of OOP will fly without it.

Comment: Just off the top of my head, Delphi and C++ have both been quite successful as OOP languages without any GC.  All you need to prevent "out of control references" is a bit of discipline. If you understand the Single Ownership Principle, (see my answer,) the problems you're talking about here become total non-issues.

Comment: @MasonWheeler:  When it's time for the owner object to be freed, it needs to know all the places that its owned objects are referenced.  Maintaining this information and using it to remove the references looks like an awful lot of work to me.  I often found the references could not be cleared quite yet.  I had to mark the owner as deleted, then bring it to life periodically to see if it could safely free itself.  I've never used Delphi, but for a small sacrifice in execution efficiency C#/Java gave me a big boost in development time over C++. (Not all due to GC, but it helped.)

Answer (score 1):

**Physical Leaks**

> The kind of bugs that GC addresses seem (at least to an external
>   observer) the kind of things that a programmer that knows well his
>   language, libraries, concepts, idioms, etc, wouldn't do. But I could
>   be wrong: is manual memory handling intrinsically complicated?

Coming from the C end which makes memory management about as manual and pronounced as possible so that we're comparing extremes (C++ mostly automates memory management without GC), I'd say "not really" in the sense of comparing to GC when it comes to *leaks*. A beginner and sometimes even a pro may forget to write `free` for a given `malloc`. It definitely does happen.

However, there are tools like `valgrind` leak detection which will immediately spot, on executing the code, when/where such mistakes occur down to the exact line of code. When that's integrated into the CI, it becomes almost impossible to merge such mistakes, and easy as pie to correct them. So it's never a big deal in any team/process with reasonable standards.

Granted, there might be some exotic cases of execution that flys under the radar of testing where `free` failed to be called, perhaps on encountering an obscure external input error like a corrupt file in which case maybe the system leaks 32 bytes or something. I think that can definitely happen even under pretty good testing standards and leak detection tools, but it would also not be quite so critical to leak a little bit of memory on something that almost never happens. We'll see a much bigger issue where we can leak massive resources even in common execution paths below in a way that GC can't prevent.

It's also difficult without something resembling a pseudo-form of GC (reference counting, e.g.) when the lifetime of an object needs to be extended for some form of deferred/asynchronous processing, perhaps by another thread.

**Dangling Pointers**

The real issue with more manual forms of memory management is not leaks to me. How many native applications written in C or C++ do we know of that are really leaky? Is the Linux kernel leaky? MySQL? CryEngine 3? Digital audio workstations and synthesizers? Does Java VM leak (it's implemented in native code)? Photoshop?

If anything, I think when we look around, the leakiest applications tend to be the ones written using GC schemes. But before that's taken as a slam on garbage collection, native code has a significant issue that's not related at all to memory leaks.

The issue for me was always safety. Even when we `free` memory through a pointer, if there are any other pointers to the resource, they will become dangling (invalidated) pointers.

When we try to access the pointees of those dangling pointers, we end up running into undefined behavior, though almost always a segfault/access violation leading to a hard, immediate crash.

All those native applications I listed above potentially have an obscure edge case or two which can lead to a crash primarily because of this issue, and there are definitely a fair share of shoddy applications written in native code which are very crash-heavy, and often in large part due to this issue.

... and it's because *resource management* is hard regardless of whether you use GC or not. The practical difference is often either leaking (GC) or crashing (without GC) in the face of a mistake leading to resource mismanagement.

**Resource Management: Garbage Collection**

Complex resource management is a difficult, manual process no matter what. GC can't automate anything here.

Let's take an example where we have this object, "Joe". Joe is referenced by a number of organizations to which he is a member. Every month or so they extract a membership fee from his credit card.

[image]

We also have one reference to Joe to control his lifetime. Let's say, as programmers, we no longer need Joe. He's starting to pester us and we no longer need these organizations he belongs to waste their time dealing with him. So we attempt to wipe him off the face of the earth by removing his lifeline reference.

[image]

... but wait, we're using garbage collection. *Every* strong reference to Joe will keep him around. So we also remove references to him from the organizations to which he belongs (unsubscribing him).

[image]

... except whoops, we forgot to cancel his magazine subscription! Now Joe remains around in memory, pestering us and using up resources, and the magazine company also ends up continuing to process Joe's membership every month.

This is the main mistake which can cause a lot of complex programs written using garbage collection schemes to leak and start using up more and more memory the longer they run, and possibly more and more processing (the recurring magazine subscription). They forgot to remove one or more of those references, making it impossible for the garbage collector to do its magic until the entire program is shut down.

The program doesn't crash, however. It's perfectly safe. It's just going to keep hogging up memory and Joe will still linger around. For many applications, this kind of leaky behavior where we just throw more and more memory/processing at the issue might be far preferable to a hard crash, especially given how much memory and processing power our machines have today.

**Resource Management: Manual**

Now let's consider the alternative where we use pointers to Joe and manual memory management, like so:

[image]

These blue links don't manage Joe's lifetime. If we want to remove him from the face of the earth, we manually request to destroy him, like so:

[image]

Now that would normally leave us with dangling pointers all over the place, so let's remove the pointers to Joe.

[image]

... whoops, we made the exact same mistake again and forgot to unsubscribe Joe's magazine subscription!

Except now we have a dangling pointer. When the magazine subscription tries to process Joe's monthly fee, the entire world will explode -- typically we get the hard crash instantly.

This same basic resource mismanagement mistake where the developer forgot to manually remove all pointers/references to a resource can lead to a lot of crashes in native applications. They don't hog up memory the longer they run typically because they will often outright crash in this case.

**Real-World**

Now the above example is using a ridiculously simple diagram. A real-world application might require thousands of images stitched together to cover a full graph, with hundreds of different types of resources stored in a scene graph, GPU resources associated to some of them, accelerators tied to others, observers distributed across hundreds of plugins watching a number of entity types in the scene for changes, observers observing observers, audios synced to animations, etc. So it might seem like it's easy to avoid the mistake I described above, but it's generally nowhere near this simple in a real-world production codebase for a complex application spanning millions of lines of code.

The chance that someone, some day, will mismanage resources somewhere in that codebase tends to be quite high, and that probability is the same with or without GC. The main difference is what will happen as a result of this mistake, which also affects potentially affects how quickly this mistake will be spotted and fixed.

**Crash vs. Leak**

Now which one is worse? An immediate crash, or a silent memory leak where Joe just mysteriously lingers around?

Most might answer the latter, but let's say this software is designed to be run for hours on end, possibly days, and each of these Joe's and Jane's we add increases the memory usage of the software by a gigabyte. It's not a mission-critical software (crashes don't actually kill users), but a performance-critical one.

In this case, a hard crash that immediately shows up when debugging, pointing out the mistake you made, might actually be preferable to just a leaky software that might even fly under the radar of your testing procedure.

On the flip side, if it is a mission-critical software where performance isn't the goal, just not crashing by any means possible, then leaking might actually be preferable.

**Weak References**

There is kind of a hybrid of these ideas available in GC schemes known as weak references. With weak references, we can have all these organizations weak-reference Joe but not prevent him from being removed when the strong reference (Joe's owner/lifeline) goes away. Nevertheless, we get the benefit of being able to detect when Joe is no longer around through these weak references, allowing us to get an easily-reproducible error of sorts.

Unfortunately weak references aren't used nearly as much as they probably should be used, so often a lot of complex GC applications might be susceptible to leaks even if they're potentially far less crashy than a complex C application, e.g.

In any case, whether or not GC makes your life easier or harder depends on how important it is for your software to avoid leaks, and whether or not it deals with complex resource management of this sort.

In my case, I work in a performance-critical field where resources do span hundreds of megabytes to gigabytes, and not releasing that memory when users request to unload because of a mistake like the above can actually be *less preferable* to a crash. Crashes are easy to spot and reproduce, making them often the programmer's favorite kind of bug, even if it's the user's least favorite, and a lot of these crashes will show up with a sane testing procedure before they even reach the user.

Anyway, those are the differences between GC and manual memory management. To answer your immediate question, I would say manual memory management is difficult, but it has very little to do with leaks, and both GC and manual forms of memory management are still *very difficult* when resource management is non-trivial. The GC arguably has more tricky behavior here where the program appears to be working just fine but is consuming more and more and more resources. The manual form is less tricky, but is going to crash and burn big time with mistakes like the one shown above.

Comment: In non-GC languages like Objective-C and Swift, weak references are an absolute necessity to handle reference cycles (basically, a weak reference cannot produce a reference cycle). In practice you use nulling weak references, which get automtatically set to nil when the object is destroyed. You need to check in the right places whether a weak reference is nil, usually together with storing it into a strong reference, so one check is enough.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a list of problems faced by C++ programmers when dealing with memory:

1. **Scoping problem** occurs in stack allocated memory: it's lifetime do not extend outside of the function where it was allocated in. There are three main solutions to this problem: heap memory, and moving the allocation point upwards in the call stack or allocating from inside objects.
2. **Sizeof problem** is in stack allocated and allocating from inside object and partly heap allocated memory: The memory block's size cannot change on the runtime. Solutions are heap memory arrays, pointers and libraries and containers.
3. **Order of definition problem** is when allocating from inside objects: the classes inside the program need to be in correct order. Solutions are restricting dependencies to a tree and reordering the classes and not using forward declarations, and pointers and heap memory and using forward declarations.
4. **Inside-Outside problem** is in object allocated memory. Memory access inside objects is divided to two parts, some memory is inside an object and other memory is outside of it, and programmers need to correctly choose to use either composition or references based on this decision. Solutions are doing the decision correctly, or pointers and heap memory.
5. **Recursive objects problem** is in object allocated memory. Size of objects becomes infinite if same object is placed inside itself, and solutions are references, heap memory and pointers.
6. **Ownership tracking problem** is in heap allocated memory, the pointer containing address of the heap allocated memory has to be passed from allocation point to deallocation point. Solutions are stack allocated memory, object-alloated memory, auto_ptr, shared_ptr, unique_ptr, stdlib containers.
7. **Ownership duplication problem** is in heap allocated memory: the deallocation can only be done once. Solutions are stack allocated memory, object-allocated memory, auto_ptr, shared_ptr, unique_ptr, stdlib containers.
8. **Null pointer problem** is in heap allocated memory: the pointers are allowed to be NULL making many of the operations crash on runtime. Solutions are stack memory, object-allocated memory and careful analysis of heap areas and references.
9. **Memory leak problem** is in heap allocated memory: Forgetting to call delete for every allocated memory block. Solutions are tools like valgrind.
10. **Stack overflow problem** is for recursive function calls which are using stack memory. Normally size of stack is completely determined on compile time, except for the case of recursive algorithms. Defining OS's stack size wrong also often causes this problem since there is no way to measure the required size of stack space.

As you can see, the heap memory is solving very many existing problems, but it causes additional complexity. GC is designed to handle part of that complexity. (sorry if some problem names are not the correct names for these problems -- sometimes it's difficult to figure out the correct name)

Comment: -1: Not an answer to the question.